# Need to Determine Power Cable For Old Bose Found In Basement

Tags: power-supply, identification

I recently purchased a home, and in the basement is a Bose Lifestyle surround sound system. The 5 speakers all plug into a base unit which I have determined is missing a power cable.

In the unit, there is this:

120V 50/60hz 350W Max

I'm not sure what all that means and when I search online I can't find anything exactly matching it. Is it something where 50 or 60 hz both would work? And where anything up to 350W would work?

The cable shape is a cross between a rectangle and an oval (rectangle with two corners rounded). Any ideas in how to identify this?

**Edit**

Here are some pictures, of the unit, of the cord input, and of the sticker.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Give me a sec and I'll edit my post in response to your pictures

Comment: Was just about to leave a comment on your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 120V 50/60hz 350W Max

This means that you can plug it directly into the wall, assuming you live in a country where the mains voltage is 120V (US, Canada, and others). 50/60Hz tells you that it will work with both 50Hz and 60Hz mains voltage, and the 350W tells you that it will draw a maximum of 350W, which means that at a nominal 120V, it will draw a maximum of 3 Amps.

That connector is tricky, however. It doesn't appear to be a standard [IEC inlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320). However, I suspect it will fit an nonstandard variant of an IEC C7 plug (sometimes designated "C7P" for "polarized"):

[image: IEC C7 nonstandard variant]

This plug is used by Bose on other equipment, and is somewhat common on consumer audio equipment. I'm not sure why the inlet on your amplifier doesn't have the bulges on the side, but in any case, it should be possible to safely use a connector of the type linked above. To verify that this connector will work, measure the pitch of the pins on that inlet. The C7 and C7 variant plug have a pin spacing of 8.6mm, center to center.

Comment: After adding C7P to my search I've found several on EBay that appear to have the correct plug, and mention Bose, so I'm going to try one of them. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that helped. Good luck!